# Parse file https with javascript using PHP

Tags: php, html, parsing

I want to do the parser of file html https://www.governo.it/it/cscovid19/report-vaccini/ with php. I try with my normal code on this case

```
<?php
$nome= "https://www.governo.it/it/cscovid19/report-vaccini/";
$lines  = @file($nome);
$i=1;
foreach($lines  as $lin )
{
$line[$i]=$lin;
$line1[$i]=strip_tags($lin);
echo "<br>$i strip tags:".$line1[$i]."<br>";
$i++;
}
?>
```

but zero result. I 've senn the code with CTRL + U there is not the rendering but only the call to js file. While if i do right click Inspect on chrome browser i see the file html with value that i need to the parser.

The file is htpps. Someone have some idea how to do the parser on this case?

Comment: You need a headless browser or browser testing tool which can execute JavaScript

Comment: Also if i used a script PHP  over on my server? Can you help me how to do? I m not able

Comment: No you can't do it with PHP alone, because PHP cannot execute JavaScript.

Comment: ok , but how can do the parser ? I need to do it. There is some way?

Comment: Please [look here](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+headless+browser+scraping). My comment earlier was intended as a hint for you to do this.

Comment: Ok thx for all , i try to do somenthing